# How to set a link using the values from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a link that placed in my view page using codeigniter

```
   <a href='".base_url()."user/pass_confirmation/$encrypted_string/$email'>
```

But the email and encrypted_string from controller..

that is not get to my view

**controller**

```
 function email_check()
{

    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    echo $email;

     $data = array(
        'user_email' =>$email, 
        );
   $result = $this->UM->email_verify($data);

   if($result)
   {
       echo $result;
       $date   = date(Y-m-d);
       $string = $email."-".$date;
       $encrypted_string = md5($string);
       echo $encrypted_string;
       $res=$this->UM->insert_key($encrypted_string,$result);

        redirect(base_url()."user/forgot_pass");
   }
 }
```

What can i do?

Comment: I can see your controller function name is **email_check()** but you have submitted to **pass_confirmation** method?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get it from the uri segments like:

```
$string = $this->uri->segment(3); 
$email = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

Comment: string and email pass to a tag in view

Answer (score 0):

like this in your route.php file:

```
$route['controllerclass/function/(:any)/(:any)'] = "pass_confirmation/$1/$2";
```

and your link will be

```
domain.com/pass_confirmation/someval/someval
```

and then you can get string and email using segment like

```
$val1 = $this->uri->segment(3); 
$val2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
```